# Converting a List of Tuples to numpy array results in single dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

We have a list of tuples in the form (year, value):

```
splist

[(2002, 10.502535211267606),
 (2003, 10.214794520547946),
 (2004, 9.8115789473684227),
  ..
 (2015, 9.0936585365853659),
 (2016, 9.2442725379351387)]
```

The intention is to convert the list of tuples to a two-D numpy array. However the published answers that use `np.asarray` retain a *single* dimension:

```
dt = np.dtype('int,float')
spp = np.asarray(splist,dt)

spp
   array([(2002, 10.502535211267606), (2003, 10.214794520547946),
   (2004, 9.811578947368423), (2005, 9.684155844155844),
   ..
   (2014, 9.438987341772153), (2015, 9.093658536585366),
   (2016, 9.244272537935139)],
  dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

This becomes clear when viewing the dimensions of the output:

```
In [155]: spp.shape
Out[155]: (15,)
```

What we *wanted*:

```
   array([[(2002, 10.502535211267606)],
        [(2003, 10.214794520547946)],
   ..
   [(2014, 9.438987341772153)], 
   [(2015, 9.093658536585366)],
   [(2016, 9.244272537935139)]])
```

So what is the magic to convert the list of tuples to a ***two*** dimensional array?

Comment: That expected `array([(2002, 10.502535211267606)],..` doesn't look like a `2D` one.

Comment: @Divakar  added the additional braces before and after .

Comment: It _still_ doesn't look like a 2D array per se. It has two dimensions, but all of the data would still be only along the 0'th dimension. i.e., the shape you describe is `(15, 1)`.

Comment: @Praveen Not sure how you arrived at that conclusion: it is a correct 2D array now. It was not previously.

Comment: This isn't a list of tuples issue.  It's a question of how to reshape a (15,) array to a (15,1) array.  Without the `dt` you would get a (15,2) array of floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your desired output correctly, you can use [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
>>> spp = np.asarray(splist, dt)
>>> spp
array([(2002, 10.502535211267606),
       (2003, 10.214794520547946),
       (2004, 9.811578947368423),
       (2015, 9.093658536585366),
       (2016, 9.244272537935139)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8')])

>>> np.reshape(spp, (spp.size, 1))
array([[(2002, 10.502535211267606)],
       [(2003, 10.214794520547946)],
       [(2004, 9.811578947368423)],
       [(2015, 9.093658536585366)],
       [(2016, 9.244272537935139)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want a two-dimensional result, just use [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), instead of `asarray`:

```
>>> a = [(2002, 10.502535211267606),
...  (2003, 10.214794520547946),
...  (2004, 9.8115789473684227),
...  (2015, 9.0936585365853659),
...  (2016, 9.2442725379351387)]
>>> np.array(a)    
array([[ 2002.        ,    10.50253521],
       [ 2003.        ,    10.21479452],
       [ 2004.        ,     9.81157895],
       [ 2015.        ,     9.09365854],
       [ 2016.        ,     9.24427254]])
>>> np.array(a).shape
(5, 2)
```

Note that this will make *both* columns of floating point dtype. It's not possible to have a 2D numpy array with different dtypes in each column. If you want to do *that*, I think Pandas has a way: though I don't have any experience with Pandas.

The only thing you can do with numpy is to have a 1D array of "object" type, with each element being a tuple - but that's what you already have with `asarray`.

Comment: `np.array` was the first thing attempted even before `asarray` . Uncertain why did not/does not work for me.

Comment: It seems to be working. I don't know what sequence of operations made it not work for me previously.

Comment: ah! I know now.  I had used a `scala` like `type-alias` as follows:   `npa=numpy.array`  . That works for *some* things but did the wrong thing in this case:   doing `spp = npa(splist)` ends up with the 15x1 instead of the 15x2 that `spp=np.array(splist)` gives.

Comment: @wwii  First: it is required to wait some time before accepting: it was still within the minimum window. Note that I had already upvoted ***both*** of them since helpful.  Second: there were two correct answers. I had to choose one and went with the other because the datatype is correct on it.

Comment: `asarray` does not make a difference.  It's the `dt` datatype that matters.